# The Screenshot widget should include the game tag or a direct link to the submission entry

Tags: feature-request, design, screenshot-of-the-week, screenshot-widget

Finding the game from the screenshot of the week in the side bar is unintuitive. Today I saw a screenshot, and was interested in it. Interested enough to go "what game is that?"

[image: Image of screenshot widget]

However the Screenshot widget on the right nav doesn't make it easy to find this information. There are 3 links and none of them easily tell me what the game is.

- **A link to the user's profile.**
  Not very helpful for me. As the link goes to the user's main profile. Additionally I'd have to filter through ~100 meta answers, or [23 submissions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A127901+%5Bscreenshot-of-the-week%5D+is%3Aanswer) if I'm well versed in SE's search.
- **A link to submit my own photo.**
  This would be helpful if the screenshot I was seeing was a new entry or the screenshot that won last week. Unfortunately the screenshot is from the #13<sup>th</sup> not the #28<sup>th</sup>/#29<sup>th</sup> screenshot of the week.
- **A link to the hall of fame.**
  This is the most helpful and is how I ultimately found the game. It was also the link I last reached for - maybe because I worked top down, left to right. However as time goes on looking through the hall of fame will become more taxing. And using ctrl-f isn't guaranteed to work, as submissions like #4 and #11 don't have any text!

This seems like quite the Easter egg hunt to find the name of the game. Whilst I like me some Easter eggs, I'm not quite as fond of the hunt. Please can Stack Exchange make finding this information easier. For example:

- **Link directly to the answer for the submission.** This would give access to things like

  - Comments on the submission
  - What the theme that week was
  - Other competing posts for that week's competition.
- **Include the game tag in the screenshot's description**; "in [rust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust) by Dragonrage".

Comment: I usually try to make sure to include the game title in the description, but that was apparently not done this time. It would be nice to be able to add a game tag, I agree

Comment: @Unionhawk Oh, I thought this was automagic like community ads

Comment: Nope, we have a little interface in our mod tools that asks for an image URL, an image description, a user URL, and the current submission question

Comment: The widget was pretty much ported as-is from Photography SE, where I assume the tag is less important. To make it a bit easier, I've added a column for the game tag to the Hall of Fame answer where we [track which screenshots have been featured there](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15367/28182)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, the photo widget is only designed so that the photo, its title, and user profile can be changed on the fly. The header and 2 links are not meant to be changed frequently.

## Short term solution

If the image title does not specify the game name, specify it instead. For your example, the title that should have been there would be:

> **Rust: "In a post-apocalyptic world, it's good to have a bunker base to keep the zergs out"** by Dragonrage ♦

## Long term [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Request that the photo widget be updated to allow moderators to edit the 2 link titles.